# Magnetic unit cell in Hofstadter model

Tags: condensed-matter

What is the best way to choose magnetic unit cell in the Hofstadter model for any $p/q$, the magnetic flux enclosed by a unit cell in the flux quantum unit $h/e$ in order to solve the eigensystem in position basis numerically?

Comment: Often the magnetic unit cell is just $q\times 1$ cells, i.e. $q$ along $x$ and $1$ along $y$. It doesn't really affect your numerics much, since in the end you always need to diagonalize $q\times q$ matrices.

Comment: In position basis it will not be $q \times q$ matrix, right?

Comment: Since you are talking about unit cells, I assume the system has magnetic translation symmetry. Then the Bloch problem you need to diagonalize is $q\times q$.

Comment: That's fine. But let's say there are open boundary conditions along $y$ direction. Then if I have $N_x \times N_y$ sites I need to diagonalize $N_xN_y \times N_xN_y$ matrix.

Comment: If $x$ is translation-invariant you can still simply it a bit by Fourier transform $x$ first, then it will be $N_yq\times N_yq$ matrix. If there is no translation invariance in either direction then you have to deal with the whole size.

Comment: Yes, wrote a Matlab program for open boundary along $y$ and periodic boundary along $x$.